# Impossible to trim an AVAsset in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avasset

I'd like to trim a video which is the only track in my AVAsset. I'd like to change the duration attribute of it but It's in read only and I haven't found any other way on the web to trim my AVAsset without exporting it.

I tried to move the playhead to the beginning at the moment where I want to cut my video but I'd like to really cut the end of my video.

Is it possible ?

Comment: show your efforts about your problem. Specify what you need and what you have done. Audio or video not specified and also not tried any code yet?

Comment: Sorry, I've update my post.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)